# SQL select 1 row out of several rows that have similar values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

| ID | OtherID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | z | 2022-09-19 |
| 1 | b | 2021-04-05 |
| 2 | e | 2022-04-05 |
| 3 | t | 2022-07-08 |
| 3 | z | 2021-03-02 |

I want a table like this:

| ID | OtherID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | z | 2022-09-19 |
| 2 | e | 2022-04-05 |
| 3 | t | 2022-07-08 |

That have distinct pairs consisted of ID-OtherID based on the Date values which are the most recent.

The problem I have now is the relationship between ID and OtherID is 1:M

I've looked at `SELECT DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, `LAG` but I couldn't figure it out. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question. I couldn't find the right keywords to search for the answer.

Update: I use Postgres but would like to know other SQL as well.

Comment: Which dbms? Look into rank() or row_number()

Comment: What engine are you using? MySQL? SQL Server, etc? Also, what are you trying to do, return the first value for each ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for many dbms (versions of postgres, mysql and others) but you may need to adapt if something else. You could use a CTE, or a join, or a subquery such as this:

```
select id, otherid, date
from (
  select id, otherid, date, 
  rank() over (partition by id order by date desc) as id_rank
  from my_table
  )z
where id_rank = 1
```

| id | otherid | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | z | 2022-09-19T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2 | e | 2022-04-05T00:00:00.000Z |
| 3 | t | 2022-07-08T00:00:00.000Z |

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (`CTE`) with `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a row number based on the `ID` column (then return the first row for each ID in the `WHERE` clause `rn = 1`):

```
WITH cte AS 
  (SELECT ID,
          OtherID, 
          Date,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
   FROM sample_table)
SELECT ID, 
       OtherID, 
       Date 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**Result:**

| ID | OtherID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | z | 2022-09-19 |
| 2 | e | 2022-04-05 |
| 3 | t | 2022-07-08 |

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/iKSzps3k).